# Room database emits all data instead of following the query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I have the following query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM newsData WHERE countryName LIKE :countryName order by publishedDateTime DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET :position")
override fun getAll(position: Int?, countryName: String): Flow<List<News>>?
```

When new data inserted in the room, instead of the emiting the selected country data, It emits all and also emit same data twice or thrice.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you log the field "countryName", LIKE operator supports wildcards options: "%" and "_"?

Comment: @MaximFirsoff I changed the LIKE with "=". Also there is no problem with the query because once data is saved in the database and I closed the app and start it again, everything works fine. 
I guess room database emits everything when something changed in it.
But still could not find the bug.

Comment: You subscribed to get `List<News>` from selected query. When selected table updated you got new list with selected query not updated items only.

Comment: @StanislavBondar Actually I implemented pagination without using the pagination3 library.
Is there anyway I can stop the whole list emission on insertion.

Comment: `LIMIT 20` will return 20 items even if one is changed

Comment: You can use `DiffUtil` to compare items and update adapter if required. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil